# schtasks "configure for (operating system)" option

Tags: operating-system, system, configure, windows-task-scheduler

I would like to know if there is a way to set option "Configure for (Operating system)" when creating scheduled task using command line? So far I could not find any command for making this selection.

Comment: I don't think so. The command line version lacks a lot of the options that are in the GUI counterpart (taskschd.msc). The only thing you can do is create the task in the GUI version, exporting the task to XML and importing this with the command line schtasks =/

Comment: I haven't been able to find an option for specifying this after substantial time searching. Often Windows lacks full coverage for all available GUI options.